# java how to know if you're running javaw.exe vs. java.exe

Tags: java, windows

Related to [Find absolute java.exe path programatically from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programatically-from-java-code) is there any way to know if the java process you're running was started as "java.exe" vs. "javaw.exe"?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the VM has no Console available (say, because you started it with javaw.exe), then a call to `System.console()` will return null.

edit:  i.e.,

```
final boolean amRunningJavaW = System.console() == null;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, I should have named the variable `probablyRunningJavaW`, since this isn't actually testing the executable process name.  :-)  And there could be other reasons why a system Console isn't available, although I don't know of any offhand.

Comment: With regards to reasons for `System.console()` returning `null`, if your application is run with its standard out stream piped to another program (e.g. more, less) or out to a file, then `System.console()` will return `null`