# Find the java.exe location from java

Tags: java, jvm

I am wondering if there is a way, from java, to find the location of the java.exe running the program?

My use case is that I am trying to have Java execute a batch script that needs JAVA_HOME to be set in the local environment. The environment that I am executing this on may not have JAVA_HOME set or even the java executable on the path, but I would assume that the JVM knows where its executable is located.

Comment: Is this the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)?

Comment: Does `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));` work?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott: That doesn't look remotely related.

Comment: Okay, what about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programatically-from-java-code)?

Comment: take a look at PeterMmm's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 System.getProperty("java.home");
```

is one option. Which shows the following directory in my machine:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre

[Most important system properties are listed here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: Nice edit completely changing your previous answer. Don't get me wrong, I like right answers, but when it's already been posted elsewhere...

Comment: yeah. so true, i usually do this wrong, rechecked the linked page and then fixed it. ;) Are you the one who down voted me? :)

Comment: @ Sage: No. By the time I got here, the incorrect answer had already been downvoted and you'd deleted it. I don't downvote correct answers, even when they really should be deleted because they duplicate other correct answers after the fact.

Comment: After the downvote i rechecked page i have linked and fixed it. But if you think that i picked it from you, i can remove it smilingly if you want. +1 for you. ;)

Comment: @ Sage: No worries, the important thing is the OP gets a resolution. Turns out this is a duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I haven't yet used to this site. Though my account was created 1 year before, i am regular here for last 17 days. I am not talking about this one but my answer collided with other question's answer in 1-2 minutes elapse, happened to me several time. I even continue to edit my answer to get things right with details for 5 - 10 times.

Comment: @ Sage: Yeah, happens all the time. Usually if I've posted an incorrect answer and later fixed it, but then notice that in the meantime, someone (hexacyanide, in this case) posted a correct one, I'll just delete mine unless it offers more information.

Comment: uhh, can't delete the accepted answer :( why is that ? sorry i have just tried to remove it but it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

The `java.home` property will supply the path to the currently running JRE, regardless of what is installed, or what `JAVA_HOME` is. See the Oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).

```
System.getProperty("java.home");
```

Comment: Already exists on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programatically-from-java-code)

Comment: That is true, but what point you are trying to make? It also exists in two other answers on this page, as well as the other question that I marked this question as a duplicate of.

Comment: It's all for naught...