# How to get the path of the current JDK in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, java-native-interface

I'm compiling a JNI library with Gradle. It clearly knows how to find a JDK (as the Java half of the project compiles perfectly). However, I'd need a path to the JNI header files in a Gradle native (C++) project.

Is there a way to obtain the path of the JDK being used from a Gradle build file?

Comment: Isn't `JAVA_HOME` env variable what you need?

Comment: thanks for the idea; it'd work if it was set, but, for me, it isn't, yet Gradle works well even without it (and it's Gradle's "reasonable defaults" that I'd need).

Comment: Did you find a way to get the path to JDK from Gradle? I have the same problem; the answer does not solves the problem (in Android Studio it yields the path to the JRE). Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

According to the top [reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programatically-from-java-code), you can get currently running Java path from the property `java.home`. In Gradle:

```groovy
    println System.getProperty('java.home')
```

or more Groovy:

```groovy
    println System.properties.'java.home'
```

Comment: I'm afraid that ONLY gives the path of the if you are compiling with the  JAVA_HOME pointing to a JDK.  When builds are cross-platform that information will not match the platform targeted.  I just checked our builds use the JDK 7 but JAVA_HOME is Java 8.  Something else must load the compiler path from the platform specified for the project.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the top answer on Google:
`Jvm.current().getJavaHome()`

Note that the `JVM` class is internal as of Gradle 6, use it at your own risk.

Comment: Fails on Gradle 7