# How do I find the location of the specific java.exe that my JVM was created by?

Tags: java, windows

I don't want to find the system's JAVA_HOME.  I don't want to lookup system variables.

I need to know exactly where a standalone (bundled JRE) is located at from within the .jar that was launched by it.

Example:  User installs application with bundled .jre, and launches it.  The program needs to determine not only the current running directory, but also the location of the java.exe that was bundled with it.  I could make assumptions based on relative path to the current running directory, but I would prefer a method of absolutely determining the full path of the currently running java.exe.  I don't believe this is a duplicate question as I have been able to find no instance of it (or an answer) that isn't answered by referring back to the system or user profile java_home.

I would think this would be a simple task, but so far have found no answer.

Comment: *"... and launches it"* how? Double-clicking a runnable jar will use the `java` from `PATH`. Otherwise it's probably from a script, where the path is coded. Besides, if you want it *"from within the jar"*, chances are *you* developped the app, and would know if you bundled a JRE (unless you developped a plugin).

Comment: May we ask why you need that path? I'm curious :)

Comment: Well, in Java 9 there is going to be a relatively simple API for this, at least if I'm reading [this](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html#command--) right. But in the current versions - it's hard.

Comment: @Matthieu: to double click a jar file, `javaw.exe` does not need to be in the path. The extension `.jar` just needs to be registered properly

Comment: Why doesn't `System.getProperty("java.home")` work for you? The only thing it does not give you if the JVM was started using `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah you're right!

Comment: @RealSkeptic can't wait...

Comment: Why do I need to know?  Because App #1 will launch App #2.  The two apps will communicate with each other allowing App #1 to shutdown App #2 whenever an updated .jar file is available.  After the update, app #1 relaunches app #2.   For stability reasons,  the app must be bundled with a JRE.  However, the user has ability to either install via unzipping the set to whatever folder structure they prefer, or to install via an installation wrapper (.msi or .exe).   I have no control over the end user's choices or installed java version.  Hence the bundled JRE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Because determining the path when it was started using java.exe or javaw.exe is exactly what I need.  The question is how to find the path of the JRE when the .jar was NOT launched via the default JVM.

Comment: `System.getProperty("java.home")` does not look at the system's PATH. It shows you the directory where the JVM is installed that is currently running. If your app is a Swing application it doesn't really matter if it was `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` - I would always use `javaw.exe` in order to start a GUI application on Windows (*especially* if it's from within another application)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on windows, have a look at the last answer on this post : [[Find absolute java.exe path programatically from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programatically-from-java-code][1])

Here is the code

```
class WhichJava {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String libPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        String exePath = libPath.substring(0, libPath.indexOf(';')) + 
                                             ((System.console() == null)? “\\javaw.exe" :”\\java.exe");
        System.out.println(exePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code arbitrarily chooses to use Java.exe. if the current JVM is ran by javaw.exe, this code wont detect that.

Comment: It should be easy to test for both or either, but if all you care about is that path to the executable, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: The OP wants the actual exe that launched his jar. How does your code provide that?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this appears to lookup based on an environment variable created by the "System's" Java installation.  The specific issue is finding the path of java.exe when the jvm is created with a bundled JRE, and not the system instance.

Comment: @Benjamin `java.library.path` is not an environment variable but a System property defined by the running JRE. It might actually be a good choice. Mine gives `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin` as the first path.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, the original post explicitly asks about finding the location of "java.exe".

Comment: Anyway, I will update my response when I can get to it, but you can find out whether it's javaw.exe vs java.exe by checking (System.console == null); if true it's javaw.exe, otherwise java.exe.

Comment: @Benjamin, I just update my post with working code.  It is not dependent on environment variables and will work for both java.exe and javaw.exe (to see output for javaw redirect it to text file using '>').