# "Resolve" javapath executables

Tags: java

I need to install software on various machines running windows OS. These machines may have different versions of JAVA installed. C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath is the path for java that can be found in system environment variables. That seems to be the most foolproof way of finding java on any given (windows) machine. However, the javapath folder only contains java.exe files. Which java are those executables referencing? Is there a way to resolve the path for the java install those .exe files belong to?

Comment: If you want this _from_ Java, dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programatically-from-java-code

Comment: @dave_thompson_085. Thanks I hadn't seen that link. I was hoping not to have to find it programatically as I am not set up with the Java SDK but I guess I'll just go ahead and set that up.